# Adding a Row Causes VBA Validation Assignment to Error Out

Tags: vba, excel

When I insert one row into a protected workbook, my VBA code that updates the validation input messages of four cells doesn't work anymore... unless I unprotect the worksheet.

The worksheet is protected with the `userinterfaceonly` property set to `true`:
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Protect password:="fa-202a", userinterfaceonly:=True`

Let me reiterate that my validation input message code works fine **until I insert a row**.

The first call to `AddNumberOfAvailableBatchesValidation` works fine.
The code throws an application-defined error on the second call to `AddNumberOfAvailableBatchesValidation`. The specific line in that sub that is failing is:

`.InputTitle = "Maximum of 100 Pouch Batches"`

As you can see it appears that it is having a problem modifying the existing data validation of the range `NamedRanges.NumBatchesAdditional1`.

Each cell of these four is a single, unmerged cell.

Here's the full code.

```
Private Sub UpdateInputMessages()
Dim numAvail As Integer

numAvail = 100 - NamedRanges.NumBatchesPrimary.Value - NamedRanges.NumBatchesAdditional1.Value - _
           NamedRanges.NumBatchesAdditional2.Value - NamedRanges.NumBatchesAdditional3.Value

AddNumberOfAvailableBatchesValidation NamedRanges.NumBatchesPrimary, numAvail
AddNumberOfAvailableBatchesValidation NamedRanges.NumBatchesAdditional1, numAvail
AddNumberOfAvailableBatchesValidation NamedRanges.NumBatchesAdditional2, numAvail
AddNumberOfAvailableBatchesValidation NamedRanges.NumBatchesAdditional3, numAvail

End Sub

Private Sub AddNumberOfAvailableBatchesValidation(target As range, numberAvailable As Integer)

With target.Validation
    .InputTitle = "Maximum of 100 Pouch Batches"
    .InputMessage = "There are " & numberAvailable & " pouch batches available."
    .ShowInput = DropdownChangeIsMultipleSelectionEligible
End With
'This is to refresh the input messages
With target
    .offset(0, 1).Select
    .Select
End With

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not have your code unprotect the sheet and then re-protect the sheet when its done?

Comment: That is certainly possible, but should be unnecessary. It works fine until I add that row.

Comment: Your code doesn't insert any row

Comment: It doesn't. This code works before I manually insert a row and doesn't work after.